# How to show jenkins.currentBuild.result to "SUCCESS" not "null"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

The problem is when the pipeline runs and passes I get "null" which I know "null" is a success. When a stage fails the notification properly shows "FAILURE"

Where should I be putting jenkins.currentBuild.result = CommonStrings.SUCCESS or what needs altered?

This is the method I utilize to make the curl:

```
def notifyTeam(String webhook2) {
    jenkins.stage('Post Build Notify Teams') {
        jenkins.echo "${jenkins.currentBuild.result}"
        String jobName = jenkins.currentBuild.fullDisplayName
        String status = jenkins.currentBuild.result
        jenkins.echo "Job Name: ${jobName} STATUS: ${status}"
        jenkins.sh "curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{\"text\": \"Job Name: ${jobName} Status: ${status} URL: <${jenkins.env.BUILD_URL}>\"}' ${webhook2}"
        jenkins.echo "${status}"
    }
}
```

This is the closure pipeline:

```
try {
        chat.prebuildChat(email, pipelineAttrs)
        pipeline.run()
        pipelineAttrs.getBuild().post()
    } catch (e) {
        jenkins.currentBuild.result = CommonStrings.FAILURE
        throw e
    } finally {
        switch (product) {
            case Product.****:
                chat.notifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
            case Product.****:
                chat.winNotifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
            case Product.****:
                chat.notifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
            case Product.****:
                chat.notifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
            case Product.****:
                chat.notifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
            case Product.****:
                chat.notifyTeam(CommonStrings.****_WEBHOOK)
                break
        }
        chat.postbuildChat(email, pipelineAttrs)
        jenkins.dir(jenkins.env.WORKSPACE) {
            jenkinsUtils.cleanupWorkspace()
        }
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
String status = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
```

Comment: this doesnt seem to work: "No such property: jenkins"

Comment: Edited: `jenkins` is not needed.